# Vim shift * in reverse to move to function call

Tags: vim

When using vim,

I frequently `shift-*` my function calls to go to the function.  If I know the function is above my cursor, but there are many functions below, how do I shift-* in reverse?

Comment: Try `shift-#` .

Comment: It's not really `shift-*`, just `*` since that incorporates the shift.  Anyways, what that does is a forward search of the word under the cursor.  `#` is the equivalent in reverse.

Comment: @AshwaniDausodia thanks!

Comment: That said, you might consider using something like ctags to actually jump to tags such as function declarations.

Comment: @ChristianGibbons I'll think Ill delete this then, since you guys are commenting.  Unless someone wants to give an answer

Comment: @ChristianGibbons I can edit to ask for tags if you think that is a big enough question for an answer

Comment: Hmm, if you wanted to reword the question, you might be able to get away with just changing the title to ask about finding the definition of a function.

Comment: I should point out that your edited title mentions 'function call' rather than 'function definition'.  A function call would be where you call the function rather than where the code for the function exists.  Finding the places where a function is called would be a different answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`*` in Normal mode will do a forward search of the word under the cursor.  From there, you can press `n` to get the next instance of the word, or you can press `N` to get the previous instance of the word.

To answer the question of searching backwards, you can use the `#` to do a reverse search for the current word.  From there, pressing `n` will get the next instance up, while `N` will reverse the reverse and search forward for the next instance.

To do what you really want to do, which is jump to a function definition, consider using `ctags`.  If you create tags for your project with a utility like `ctags` or `etags`, you can use <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>]</kbd> to jump to the definition of a function under the cursor.  If it's in the same file (which considering you are doing a search to get this kind of functionality, should apply to your current situation), I think it may be able to work to some extent even without setting up the tags file.

If you are also interested in finding where a function is called (in `c`, at least), there's another utility called `cscope` that can be of help.  Like with the ctags, you'll need to build the `cscope.out` file using the cscope utility.  Once you do, you can use vim's cscope hooks.  To get a list of calls to a function with cscope, you can invoke it with this (note that  is <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>R</kbd>):

```
:cs find c <C-R>=expand("<cword>")
```

That's a bit of a handful to write out all the time, so I put this in my .vimrc so it can be invoked `g[`:

```
nnoremap g[ :cs find c <C-R>=expand("<cword>")<CR><CR>
```